# Ballerina vscode plugin warns ballerina home setting is invalid. What is correct setting for windows 10 PC?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-vscode-plugin

Have installed latest (as of 28/2/21) versions of ballerina (swan lake alpha2) and VSCode plugin (1.2.13). When I look at a .bal src file the 'language intelligence' seems to work correctly but the 'show file overview reports errors. The errors I get are:

Ballerina extension did not start properly. Please check extension logs for more info.

And logs:

Ballerina home is configured in settings.
Configured Ballerina home is not valid.
Failed to activate Ballerina extension. Configured Ballerina home is not valid.

I must be missing something with the setting but cannot identify what. Two obvious settings I have tried are:

c:\program files\ballerina\bin & c:\program files\ballerina

Thanks for any guidance

Answer (score 3):

The VSCode plugin version `1.2.13` is incompatible with `swan lake alpha2`. You have to download and install the compatible VSCode extention version available at [Swan Lake Alpha2 section in download page](https://ballerina.io/downloads/). You can find that at the bottom of that section.

Direct Link: https://github.com/ballerina-platform/plugin-vscode/releases/download/vswan-lake-alpha2/ballerina-swan-lake-alpha2.vsix

Once downloaded, you have to install that extension using the `Install from VSIX` option (In the hamburger menu of the extensions tab).

**Update**

Ballerina [VSCode plugin compatible with Swan Lake is now available](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WSO2.ballerina) in visual studio marketplace

Comment: Thanks for that - moved forward but now getting the following: Ballerina home is configured in settings.
Failed to activate Ballerina extension. Error when checking ballerina version. AggregateError: All promises were rejected

Comment: In VSCode, can you check the extension settings; `File -> Preferences -> Settings`, in that go to `Extensions -> Ballerina` and check if `Home` is set to some directory. If yes, clear that. You can also try uninstalling the extension (both new and old) and reinstalling again. Let me know the progress.

Comment: Also, check if `Dev Mode` is disabled under `Ballerina Plugin` settings (same place as where we had `Home`)

Comment: Hi Imesha - thanks for your help - still giving the error - have tried with & without home set, uninstalled & reinstalled and disabled dev mode all to no avail :(. Just one point of clarity - in your first response yesterday you said uninstall the extension (both old and new) & reinstall. Do you mean I should have both old and new installed? I assume not?

Comment: At a given time, we will have one version installed. In this case, we need the swan lake alpha version's plugin installed. Can you check if `bal` command is working in your terminal? Try `bal version`.

Comment: Hi - A couple of things - I need to go to c:\balleina\bin to run bal, also get a warning about not being a path PS loads from and to use .\bal version. Then I get the following: The system cannot find the file C:\Users\tim.
Ballerina Swan Lake Alpha 2
Language specification v2020-12-17
Update Tool 0.8.20

Comment: In that case, you don't have `ballerina/bin` directory in `path` environment variable. Usually the VSCode plugin picks the `bal` command from PATH. In your case, you have to set the `Home` under ballerina extension settings and then enable `Dev Mode`. This is because you don't have the `bal` command available via `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the variable %Ballerina_Home% was set to the right path the in the path it was set to %Ballerina_Home%\bin. sorting that and un ticking dev mode and removing the ballerina settings and the plugin seems to load - but still there is no option to show graphical view.

Comment: @TimH Happy to hear you got that working. Regarding the graphical view, it is not yet included in `swan lake alpha 2` which is the latest release. The plan is to add that in `swan lake beta` onward.

Comment: Ok - thanks for the info - looking forward to the beta release. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Great! No problem!

Comment: I'm having the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04 for `swan-lake-beta1`. `bal` command is working from the terminal but I need sudo permissions for that. Can this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the extension as described by @Imesha you should add the ballerina home to the PATH.
On Mac

```
vi .zshrc

export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/ballerina/1.2.13/libexec/bin/
```

Comment: Further, I have installed  pkg(ARM64) 235mb from [1]
So, the path should be added to the ~/.zshrc below.
`export PATH="/Library/Ballerina/bin:$PATH"`


[1] https://ballerina.io/downloads/

Comment: The path setting you've provided above seems incomplete. The export line should end with a closing double quote. Here's the corrected version:

export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/ballerina/1.2.13/libexec/bin/"